# no module named 'pyscipopt'

Tags: python, scip

I have already installed pyscipopt.

I type `pip install pyscipopt` in command prompt.

I also can run my script using IDLE (Python 3.6 64-bit).

But when I want to run it using command prompt, I got `ModuleNotFoundError`. It said that "No module named 'pyscipopt'".

Comment: which version did you install, for python 2 or 3?
and which version is running from cmd..100% sure you are running the wrong version ;)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't realize it. Thank you so much for the answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have more than one versions in your PC. So when you run `pip install`,the default version will install pyscipopt instead of 3.6.

Try this:

```
C:\>path\to\python3.6.exe -m pip install -U pyscipopt
```

Comment: I didn't realize I have two versions in my PC. It has been resolved. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please accept my answer so it can help others see it too :)

Comment: Also, make sure to use virtual environments whenever possible. They make handling dependencies and different python version a lot easier.